# When I change the date format datatables not working

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

When I change the date format to DD.MM.YYYY. The datatables date filter is not working otherwise (YYYY-MM-DD) it works. Please check the link and help me. It's a working link with (YYYY-MM-DD) format.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evcfespn/102/)

I changed the date format to `DD.MM.YY` in js code and HTML but not working the date filter

`$(this).val(picker.startDate.format('DD.MM.YYYY') + ' to ' + picker.endDate.format('DD.MM.YYYY'));`

**HTML**

```
<td>15.10.2016</td>
```

**JS**

```
/Start of the data table    
$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip'
  });
$("div.toolbar").html('<input id="date_range" type="text">');  
//END of the data table

// Date range script - Start of the sscript
$("#date_range").daterangepicker({
    autoUpdateInput: false,
    locale: {
        "cancelLabel": "Clear",
        }
});

$("#date_range").on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
      table.draw();
});

$("#date_range").on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      $(this).val('');
      table.draw();
});
// Date range script - END of the script

$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {

    var grab_daterange = $("#date_range").val();
    var give_results_daterange = grab_daterange.split(" to ");
    var filterstart = give_results_daterange[0];
    var filterend = give_results_daterange[1];
    var iStartDateCol = 4; //using column 2 in this instance
    var iEndDateCol = 4;
    var tabledatestart = aData[iStartDateCol];
    var tabledateend= aData[iEndDateCol];

    if ( !filterstart && !filterend )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if ((moment(filterstart).isSame(tabledatestart) || moment(filterstart).isBefore(tabledatestart)) && filterend === "")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if ((moment(filterstart).isSame(tabledatestart) || moment(filterstart).isAfter(tabledatestart)) && filterstart === "")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if ((moment(filterstart).isSame(tabledatestart) || moment(filterstart).isBefore(tabledatestart)) && (moment(filterend).isSame(tabledateend) || moment(filterend).isAfter(tabledateend)))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
);

//End of the datable
 });
```

Comment: If you wouldn't mind setting up a JSFiddle (or equivalent) it would be much easier to help.